# Merge a list of dicts without overwriting

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to merge a list of dicts without losing any data.

I have:

```
a = [{'ArticleUrl': 'a', 'Text': 'labor activists negative'},
{'ArticleUrl': 'a', 'Text': 'funds negative'},
{'ArticleUrl': 'b', 'Text': 'Timothy S. Hillman negative'},
{'ArticleUrl': 'b', 'Text': 'AFT negative'},
{'ArticleUrl': 'c', 'Text': 'major outages negative'}]
```

and what I want to get is:

```
b = [{'ArticleUrl': 'a','Text': 'labor activists negative, funds negative'},
{'ArticleUrl': 'b', 'Text': 'Timothy S. Hillman negative, AFT negative'},
{'ArticleUrl': 'c', 'Text': 'major outages negative'}]
```

I have tried .update but it seems to overwrite the 'text' values. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Consider using lists for the values, rather than concat the strings.  Concat *is* losing data (you no longer know where the boundaries were).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging different keys inside a list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019571/merging-different-keys-inside-a-list-of-dictionaries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create another dict, update it while iterating the list and take the values.

```
lst = [{'ArticleUrl': 'a', 'Text': 'labor activists negative'},
{'ArticleUrl': 'a', 'Text': 'funds negative'},
{'ArticleUrl': 'b', 'Text': 'Timothy S. Hillman negative'},
{'ArticleUrl': 'b', 'Text': 'AFT negative'},
{'ArticleUrl': 'c', 'Text': 'major outages negative'}]


dict_results = {}

for d in lst:
    k = d['ArticleUrl']
    if k in dict_results:
        dict_results[k] += ", " + d['Text']
    else:
        dict_results[k] = d['Text']

lst = [{'ArticleUrl': k, 'Text': v} for (k,v) in dict_results.items()]
#[{'ArticleUrl': 'a', 'Text': 'labor activists negative, funds negative'}, {'ArticleUrl': 'b', 'Text': 'Timothy S. Hillman negative, AFT negative'}, {'ArticleUrl': 'c', 'Text': 'major outages negative'}]
```